# Javascript accessing values of map through key objects that have equal fields but are not the same in memory

Tags: javascript, hashmap

The following code prints undefined because in memory a and b are not the same.

```
let map = new Map();

let obj1 = {value1: 1, value2: 2};
let obj2 = {value1: 1, value2: 2};

map.set(obj1, 'someValue');
console.log(map.get(obj2));
```

I'm looking for a way to access the value stored 'someValue' with key the object obj1 with another key obj2 that is equal in terms of fields.

Comment: you need the same object reference or a primitive value.

Comment: My mistake, ill edit the post, and yes stringify would work.

Comment: You should be careful with `stringify` unless you know the property order of the objects will always be the same.

Comment: Any other alternative then instead of stringify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create hash from your object. Plain stringify might fail in case your properties are in different order. For example:

```
JSON.stringify({a: 1, b:2}) !== JSON.stringify({b: 2, a:1})
```

You can use module like [hashcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashcode) or [object-hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-hash) to create hash, like:

```
map.set(encode().value(obj1), 'someValue')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the entries of the object and sort them for getting a comparable JSON.

```js
function getEntries(object) {
    return JSON.stringify(Object
        .entries(object)
        .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
    );
}

var map = new Map(),
    obj1 = { value1: 1, value2: 2 },
    obj2 = { value2: 2, value1: 1 };

map.set(getEntries(obj1), 'someValue');
console.log(map.get(getEntries(obj2)));
```